# Using *.stl files as parameters for Gazebo creations

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Aloha ROSians! I am fairly new to ROS, as I am sure my problem lies with a rudimentary misunderstanding of the file structure of ROS, but nonetheless it is a problem that stumped several of us for a couple of hours today.

After finding out that Gazebo could use a STL file as its parameters, we attempted to make it work for us using first a .dea file, and then a stl file.  our .urdf looks like this:

```
<robot name="robot_of_doom">
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="2 0 0" /> 
      <mass value="1.0" />
      <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="100.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>  
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.15 0 0.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects/plate2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="my_box">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

Our plate2.stl is in the same location as our urdf file, and previously, when we were attempting to piecemeal the robot together we were at least able to see the individual components that we had created.

Can you see what we are doing incorrectly, and how to best correct it?

Thank you!

[Any other details needed can be provided, please let me know how I can help you help me! ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28577/using-*.stl-files-as-parameters-for-gazebo-creations./) by [JLMarks](https://answers.ros.org/users/1862/jlmarks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-02-27**:
I don't understand well your problem JLMarks, Can't you see any *.stl file in GAZEBO??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Is your plate2.stl really in the gazebo_worlds package, and not in your own package (e.g. robot_of_doom_description)? You say it is in the same location as your attached URDF - if this is in your own package, as it should be, the path to the STL file is obviously wrong.
2. Once you have the right path, try to load the URDF in Rviz:
   **roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=robot_of_doom.urdf**

If it works in Rviz, I am not entirely shure what the problem can be, as I am not shure what the next step is in making a working model in Gazebo. But let me know how it goes.

---

Originally posted by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) with karma: 100 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1